# Deducing Archimedes's Principle from the momentum equation for incompressible fluids

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

Consider an incompressible fluid, with constant density $\rho$, subject to a conservative
body force, so that $g = −∇\chi$ for some potential function $\chi$.

$$\frac{ \partial{\textbf{u}}}{\partial{t} } +(\nabla \times \textbf{u} ) \times \textbf{u} = -\nabla \Big( \frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2} |\textbf{u}|^2 +\chi \Big)$$

Where $p$ is the pressure

How can you deduce  Archimedes’ Principle from this, that an oject immersed in a fluid at rest experiences a buoyancy force equal to the weight of fluid displaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half a year had past and it's ripe to answer the question :-)

It is fairly easy. First, since Archimedes’ Principle is essentially about hydrostatics, then $\boldsymbol u = 0$, i.e. nothing moves. Thus your equation turns into

$$\nabla p = - \rho \boldsymbol g$$

Then you have to integrate pressure over the whole body's surface to find the force exerted on the body by the fluid:

$$\boldsymbol F = \int_S p \cdot d \boldsymbol s = \int_V \nabla p \, dV = - \rho \boldsymbol g \int_V dV = - \rho V \boldsymbol g$$

$V$ is the volume of the body, $S$ is its surface. That's all. I've used [Gauss theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) here:

$$\int_V \left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}\right)dV=\int_S(\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}) \, dS$$

However as you see I've integrated $\nabla p$ *inside* the body, just like there was fluid and no body. If you are a mathematician, I think you may say that given $p(\boldsymbol x)$ satisfying the hydrostatic equation outside the body, there is a unique smooth continuation of $p$ inside the body, satisfying the same equation.

But I'm rather a physician and I would say, that we can substitute the body by a bubble full of fluid and the forces acting on that bubble *from the outside fluid* won't change. That's just because these forces depend only on the shape of the body.

**UPD** Oops, I've missed the minus sign, I've corrected it --- the force exerted on the body is opposite to $\boldsymbol g$.

Comment: I would have put it the other way round. I would use Archimedes principle to derive the integral form of the governing equation. But it is Gauss in one direction or the other